# Windows event message viewer for viewing messages sent by PostMessage() function

Tags: winapi, message-queue, viewer

Couple of years ago i used some tool to monitor what event messages were being sent to a window. I can't remember the name right now. Can someone please tell me some tool with this functionality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are looking for a free alternative, give [Winspector](http://www.softpedia.com/get/Security/Security-Related/Winspector.shtml) a try ([Official website](http://web.archive.org/web/20080425103619/www.windows-spy.com/) seems to be down at the moment)

Answer (score 2):

[Spy++](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa242713%28v=VS.60%29.aspx), that is typically packaged with VS.

Answer (score 0):

Spy from Visual Studio

Answer (score 0):

If it was Visual Studio you used, it was probably [Spy++](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa264396%28VS.60%29.aspx) you remember. Alternatives are WinSpy, and WinSight, that comes with Borland products (C++ and Delphi)

Comment: Borland stopped developing WinSight a long time ago.  It is not shipped anymore.